# JavaScript DOM object to jQuery object

Tags: dom, jquery

How can I convert a JavaScript DOM object to a jQuery object?

```
<tr onclick="changeStatus(this)">

function changeStatus(myObject) {
       XXX.removeClass();
}
```

What should I write in place of XXX?
I know I can make a workaround using an id and an id selector, but it is not so elegant. 
Is there any way to convert a js DOM object to a jQuery object or using the `this` keyword in jQuery?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
var $this = $(myObject);
```

`$this` is a jQuery object. You can create jQuery objects from DOM elements.

```
<tr onclick="changeStatus(this)">

function changeStatus(myObject) {
       $(myObject).removeClass();
}
```

I would like to recommend doing your event binding with jQuery as well:

```
<tr class="change-status">

$('.change-status').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass( ... );
});
```

This is nice because now all the JS code is in one place and can be updated (in my opinion) more easily. Note that the class I added to the `<tr>` element is not necessary if you want to bind to all `<tr>` elements in the DOM.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the event handler being in JavaScript. But there are situations where defining the event handler is not in your hand. For example a third party plugin where `click` event is handled by them. So your first example helped me more. Anyway perfect solution!

Answer (score 13):

Simply wrap the pass the DOM object in as the first argument.

```
$(myObject).removeClass('foo');
```

Comment: Simplest.  Works for me.