# How do i just rotate a image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, syntax, rotation, angle

I am working on a program in Javascript while I tried to rotate my image I have drawn. I tried to search on google to find my answer but all I got was how to rotate the whole canvas. What I am searching for is a way to rotate just an image (think like this. I want to rotate a warrior dependent on the direction he is walking in). I tried many different codes but all went to the same, rotate the whole canvas.

Here is an example of what I used:

```
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
```

and also:

```
var angle = 0; //init angle
images[0].onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0);
    setInterval(function () {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(-ctx.canvas.width / 2, -ctx.canvas.height / 2, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (angle += 10)); //rotating at 10 degrees interval..
        ctx.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0);
        ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);
        ctx.restore();
    }, 16);
}
```

please help me out

Comment: Try this jQuery plugin , yet great examples : http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Comment: The problem is i will get a new problem. How do i call a function in a JQuery file from a JavaScript file?

Comment: Like this call js to jq object-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489779/javascript-dom-object-to-jquery-object ,for exp: `var jsObj=document.getElementByTageName("title");var jqObj=$(jsObj).html();$(jsObj).html("jQuery Test");`

Comment: The code seems fine, saving and restoring the context should allow you to rotate just the image. Everything drawn before and after shouldn't be affected. Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: here is the "game" right now:

http://berzanlabb.se/te11e/robrot060/JavaScript/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The rotating of the canvas is part of how to create the rotation relative to the image.
To keep the image's visible position the same and not move it, you have to center it first.
Without centering the image you will only acheive the visual effect of rotating the **entire** canvas.
You have to throw in a bit of math to get it to rotate around the center of the image.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x, y); /*X and Y of the image, center point of the image */
ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotation); /*rotation is in degrees, so this converts it to rads */
ctx.drawImage(img, -(img.width/2), -(img.height/2)); /* Draw and center the image */
ctx.restore();
```